# Localization of Minimal free Resolution

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $(R,m)$ be a local ring and $p \in \operatorname{Spec}(R)$.

Let $$\cdots \longrightarrow F_n \longrightarrow F_{n-1}\longrightarrow\dots\longrightarrow F_1\longrightarrow F_0 \longrightarrow M\longrightarrow0$$ be a minimal free resolution of $M$. Then $$\cdots \longrightarrow (F_n)_p \longrightarrow (F_{n-1})_p\longrightarrow\cdots\longrightarrow (F_1)_p\longrightarrow (F_0)_p \longrightarrow M_p\longrightarrow0$$ is a free resolution of $M_p$ (since localization preserves exactness).

*Question:* Is it a minimal free resolution of $M_p$ over $R_p$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, not necessarily. The localized resolution will be minimal again if and only if the matrix entries of the original resolution not only belonged to ${\mathfrak m}$ but even to ${\mathfrak p}$.

In the extreme case, if $R$ is a domain you could take ${\mathfrak p}=(0)$, in which case $R_{\mathfrak p}=\text{Quot}(R)$, and the localized resolution is minimal if and only if $F_i=0$ for all $i>0$ (that is, if $M$ was free).

Comment: excellent answer Hanno! +1 for "the extreme case"